# Configuring debugging of imported JS modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm in the process of building my first Vue.js app, and I'm struggling with debugging behaviour when working with imported modules. For example, where I import `someModule.js` from `/src/lib`.

I seem to be able to configure `launch.json` such that either:

A. I can debug the imported modules (at the expense of finding that breakpoints within .vue files become unbound). *OR*...
B. I can debug the vue components (at the expense of finding that breakpoints within the imported files become unbound).

The respective launch configurations are:

```
    ...
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "A: Imported Modules",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "B: Vue Modules",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        }
    },...
```

Can anyone shed some light on the possibility of being able to use the debugger with both vue project files and imported JS modules? If so, where am I going wrong?

Thanks,

Nick